# ERROR- 'The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous' in Prediction of **Sentimental Analysis**

Tags: python

```
This is my predictive array which i have calculated separately
model.predict(x_test) 
array([[0.53189766, 0.5206426 , 0.5028406 ],
      [0.49872813, 0.49236214, 0.46486002],
      [0.5356784 , 0.6017476 , 0.46934658],
       ...,
      [0.5134366 , 0.50351447, 0.5025247 ],
      [0.5107351 , 0.5409793 , 0.5059488 ],
      [0.47921842, 0.4638722 , 0.50206804]], dtype=float32)
```

Now when I am trying to make a **function** where it will show the 'positive', 'negative', 'neutral' 
it is giving me **more than one element is ambiguous error**

```
def preprocess(text):
  review=re.sub('@\S+|https?:\S+|http?:\S|[^A-Za-z0-9]+',' ',text)
  review=review.lower()
  review=review.split()
  review=[word for word in review if not word in stop_words]
  print(review)
  review=pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([review]), maxlen=300)
  return review 

def prediction(review):
  review=preprocess(review)
  score=model.predict(review)
  score=score[0]
  if score<0.4:
    print("Negative")
  elif score>0.4 and score<0.6:
    print("Neutral")
  else:
    print("Positive")
  print(score)

prediction("the food is not bad")


this is my error code-
['food', 'bad']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-b47bdbfca359> in <module>()
----> 1 prediction("the food is not bad")

<ipython-input-90-1974b824c005> in prediction(review)
  3     score=model.predict(x_test)
  4     score=score[0]
----> 5     if score<0.4:
  6         print("Negative")
  7     elif score>0.4 and score<0.6:
```

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Try print your score variable before "if score<0.4:".

Comment: @JoãoVictor - i didn't get you

Comment: I can't test your code because it is not complete. But the error is "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous". It means you are trying to compare an array to a float.

Comment: @JoãoVictor i can share it with you from google drive, if can give me your gmail address.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: @AMC- & is not working for me